# Join two lists into one list

Tags: c#, list, join, lambda

I have two lists from two different tables; the lists are from different dbs and I need to join or create a new list with the result of the two list(tables), where the value from list 2 are equals to the values of the list 1

Table 1 `ItemList`

### Order| Material |Quantity   |Desc        | Batch

```
11| M1       | 1         |Description |x1
22| M3       | 2         |apple       |x2
32| M1       | 10        |banana      |x3
11| M5       | 30        |Description |x4
```

Table 2 `ItemSell`

### Order| Material |Quantity    |Desc        | Batch

```
11| M1       | 12         |Description |x1
22| M3       | 21         |apple       |x2
```

Result

### Order| Material |Stock      |Desc         | Batch| sell

```
11| M1       | 11         |Description |x1    | 12
22| M3       | 2          |apple       |x2    | 21
32| M1       | 10         |banana      | x3   |0
```

My code is this:

```
result.AddRange(
ItemList.Select(x=>x).Distinct()
.Join(
    ItemSell.Distinct(),
    stock => stock.Material.ToUpper().Trim(),
    sell => sell.Material.ToUpper().Trim(),
    (stock,sell) => newsellItems
    {
        Stock=stock.Quantity,
        sell=sell.Quantity,
        Desc=stock.Desc,
        Batch=stock.Batch,
        Material=stock.Material,
        Order=stock.Order
    }
    ).ToList()
);
```

With this code I only get these values

Result

### Order| Material |Stock      |Desc         | Batch| sell

```
11| M1       | 11         |Description |x1    | 12
22| M3       | 2          |apple       |x2    | 21
```

Comment: From what you've shown, the Material column in the first table, which is what you're keying on, does not have unique values.  Also, what's with the last row?  Is "Description" a generic placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work. I tried a nearly identical example in LINQPad and got the results you were expecting:

```
var stockItems = new[] 
{ 
    new { Order = 11, Material = "M1", Quantity = 1, Desc = "Description", Batch = "x1" }, 
    new { Order = 22, Material = "M3", Quantity = 2, Desc = "apple", Batch = "x2" }, 
    new { Order = 32, Material = "M1", Quantity = 10, Desc = "banana", Batch = "x3" },
    new { Order = 11, Material = "M5", Quantity = 30, Desc = "Description", Batch = "x4" },
};

var sellItems = new[]
{
    new { Order = 11, Material = "M1", Quantity = 12, Desc = "Description", Batch = "x1" }, 
    new { Order = 22, Material = "M3", Quantity = 21, Desc = "apple", Batch = "x2" }
};

stockItems
    .Distinct()
    .Join(
        sellItems.Distinct(), 
        stock => stock.Material.ToUpper().Trim(), 
        sell => sell.Material.ToUpper().Trim(), 
        (stock, sell) => new
        {
            Order = stock.Order,
            Material = stock.Material,
            Stock = stock.Quantity,
            Desc = stock.Desc,
            Batch = stock.Batch,
            Sell = sell.Quantity
        })
    .ToList()
    .Dump();
```

Result:

```
Order | Material | Stock | Desc        | Batch | Sell
11    | M1       | 1     | Description | x1    | 12 
22    | M3       | 2     | apple       | x2    | 21 
32    | M1       | 10    | banana      | x3    | 12
```

There must be something wrong with your test, or you haven't pasted in exactly the code you have.